# Adding a link using JQuery html() is not click-able on IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add html to a page using JQuery's html() function. This works great on most browsers except IE6.

I can work round this by adding a click event etc but I want to fix the issue without extra tape!

Any ideas why this doesn't work on IE6?

```
$('#button_holder').html('<a href="#" onclick="run_activity_upload(); return false;" id="save_button">Upload</a>');
```

Thanks,
Abs

Comment: Is this inside a `li`? Can you show the surrounding HTML?

Comment: use jQuery.browser [ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ ] to see the user is using IE6 and redirect them to gtfo.html

Comment: No its not inside an `li` this is just a `div` (button_holder), within a `div` (wrapper).

Comment: @Bala - as much as I would like to do that this is an app for the public sector and they don't know anything else other than IE6. :)

Comment: @Bala R: I couldn't tell if you were joking or not, but I 1-upped your comment anyway :-P

Comment: It's not "extra red tape". The way you're embedding javascript functionality is directly counter what jQuery helps fix. It's bad design, so I'm not going to bother helping you to debug. Also, you didn't say what version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: @Stefan - you misunderstood what I meant by "tape". I wasn't referring to bureaucracy and I also meant that I don't want to write extra code for IE6. Nothing to do with bashing how JQuery should be used. The version of JQuery I am running is `1.3.2`.

Comment: Are you saying the code doesn't fire at all? It works just fine for me on IE6 with jQuery 1.3.2.

Comment: You misunderstood how I meant "extra red tape." You wanted to do this **the wrong way**. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this?

```
// add html
$('#button_holder').html('<a href="#" id="save_button">Upload</a>');

// add click listener on save button
$('#save_button').click(function(e) {
    run_activity_upload();
    e.preventDefault();    // same as return false in onclick
});
```

Comment: Oh I am sorry to read only half of it -  You don't want to add a separate click listener.

Comment: I was hoping not to do the above but I think it'll take me a while to figure out what's wrong with IE6 so I think the above is the correct solution annoyingly! :) It's better practice too.